# How can Garrosh still live?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So I understand that Garrosh used a time portal to go back Draenor before the Orcs got corrupted by the demon blood, but what I don't understand is, we killed him in SoO, which means he had to activate the time portal before, so how could we fight him if he wasn't even there, or was that like a duplicate of him or something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**He never died.**

He wasn't killed in SoO, you probably skipped the [cutscene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXKMHMQNo8I) at the end of the raid? 
The Pandaren arrested him for trial, but he was able to escape ([Kairozdormu](http://wowpedia.org/Kairozdormu) helped him) and used the time portal afterwards.

Comment: The trial and escape is described in the Warcrimes novel.

Comment: Mr T. helped him escape by using a Mohawk Grenade.

Comment: I find this stupid when I did the raid cause I really wanted to kill Garrosh!

Comment: This is not entirely correctly. He didn't use time portal, but portal to parallel universe which happens to have time off-set of 30 years. Don't look at me, Blizzard said so...

Comment: @StupidOne - "A wizard did it" has been Blizzard's go-to reasoning for a lot of things. This is their way around time travel paradoxes.

Comment: @StupidOne Source? You've mangled the explanation. Warlords of Draenor is set in a parallel universe created when Garrosh interferes with the timeline 30 years in the past (see [Many-worlds theory](http://www.universetoday.com/113900/parallel-universes-and-the-many-worlds-theory/)). A few years after that interference, the Iron Horde finishes a portal to connect to our universe at a time shortly after Garrosh has left it. So the universes are also not in sync in time. Calling the first portal a "parallel universe" portal instead of a "time portal" is splitting hairs.

Comment: Also, at the end of the Garrosh fight, he's listed as "Unconscious" instead of as a corpse or dead.

Comment: @ghoppe It is actually a parallel/alternate universe, not just 30 years in past. A bunch of things are different in AU Draenor compared to ours.

Comment: @Coxy I guess in the novelization Kairozdormu says it's a "timeway similar to the past of their own, but 'not a perfect mirror image.'" My point is, it's just a matter of semantics. Calling it a time portal is not inaccurate. All time portals go to parallel universes using the many-worlds logic of time travel.

Comment: @ghoppe It's a way more than semantics. If it was time portal and not portal to parallel universe, there wouldn't be green orcs on Azeroth (as Gromamsh never drinked the Mannoroth's blood)

Comment: @StupidOne You're putting your own definition on "time portal." In the novelization, Kairozdormu talks about "timeways". They call it a time portal. It's a portal to a different "timeway". Different timeways are alternate universes. It *is* semantics, since everyone agrees it's parallel universes, but it's also universes separated by time. So what's the big deal calling it a time portal?

Comment: @StupidOne The point is, Garrosh changed the future destiny of that parallel universe (timeway) which was about to follow the same course of his universe (green orcs.)

Comment: @ghoppe If you are so much into novels -> War of the Ancients time travel, Twilight of the Aspects parallel universe. WoD -> Same as TotA. Like I said at my very first comment, I didn't came up with that definition - go to youtube and watch Lore panel about WoD from Blizzcon.

Answer (score 3):

## Garrosh Didn't Die in Siege of Orgrimmar

As stated previously, [Garrosh](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=71865) didn't die in the [Siege of Orgrimmar](http://www.wowhead.com/zone=6738/siege-of-orgrimmar) raid. He is in fact arrested and sent to trial. That trial and the aftermath of that trial is detailed in the [War Crimes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1451684487) novel.

[Kairozdormu](http://wowpedia.org/Kairozdormu) tweaked time and space with his "device" which allowed them to travel to an alternate reality (universe) in the not too distant past. Kairozdormu referred to them as timeways in the shortstory [Hellscream](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/game/lore/savage-world/hellscream/page-1). These alternate universes, which are apparently infinite, are also experienced by Thrall in the novel [Thrall: Twilight of the Aspects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143919663X).

Quotes from Hellscream short story:

> "Because most of the hourglass is still in our Azeroth, this piece resonates with our timeway. Call it a glimpse… a glint of time. With a little work on my part—"
>
> "We can go back." Garrosh felt his heart race and his skin tingle. Plans began to unfold within his mind. "Not just back to our Azeroth. It could take us back to our time."
>
> "And that is just the beginning," Kairoz said. He turned around, gesturing toward the sun dipping low on the Nagrand horizon. "First Azeroth. Then other worlds. All of them. As many as we need." The bronze dragon began to laugh. "We will be limited by nothing. Not even time. The possibilities are infinite. I will become infinite—"

You do confront Garrosh again, in Draenor, on a [quest chain](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=35171) that takes place in Nagrand.